# Can I pass a literal $ into a bash script from the command line?

Tags: bash, variables

I'm creating a bash script and I need to be able to accept a string as the first parameter. This string may contain the `$` character.

###### Script

```sh
#/bin/bash
pass="$1"
echo $pass
```

###### Output

```sh
root@server:/home# ./test.sh abc$xyz
abc
```

As you can see, the `$` in the input is causing a problem because it's trying to interpret it as `$xyz` instead of a literal. Returning `abc$xyz` would be considered a successful response.

Comment: Your shell is doing that, _before_ the script gets called.

Comment: You should be running it as `./test.sh 'abc$xyz'`

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke:

```
$ ./test.sh abc$xyz
```

the shell parses that line by first looking for a variable named `xyz`.  If that variable is unset, then `$xyz` expands to the null string and `./test.sh abc$xyz` becomes `./test.sh abc`.  If you want to pass the literal string `abc$xyz` to your script, you should quote it to prevent the shell from doing any interpolation:

```
$ ./test.sh 'abc$xyz'
```

On an unrelated note, don't use the `.sh` suffix on your scripts. ([https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/](https://www.talisman.org/%7Eerlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)).  But in this case, you shouldn't just remove the suffix, since `test` is also a terrible name for a script.

Comment: I happen to very proud of that meticulously thought out name. I might be offended, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose in single quotes characters or sections of the string to prevent the shell from interpreting them.

Alternatively, escape some special characters that are normally interpreted. Echo below shows what would be passed to a script:

```
echo Hi'\'myFriend     =>  Hi\myFriend
echo Hi\$myFriend      =>  Hi$myFriend
echo Hi\"myFriend\"    =>  Hi"myFriend"
echo 'Hi "$myFriend"'  =>  Hi "$myFriend"
echo "Hi $myFriend"    =>  Hi
```